# Inequality with generalized Hardy operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I am studying the property of Generalized Hardy operators and I am wondering under  which conditions on $\phi_1, \phi_2$ and $k$ the following inequality would hold:

$$
\left(\int_0^{\infty}\left(\int_t^{\infty}k^*(s)g^*(s)\right)t^q\phi_1(t)dt\right)^{1/q}\leq C \left(\int_0^{\infty}g^{**}(t)^p\phi_2(t)dt\right)^{1/p},
$$

where $p,q\geq 2$ and $\phi_1, \phi_2$ are weights.